# Display JLabel partially on top of another JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, miglayout

I'm trying to display cards in my GUI and I want to overlap cards to save on space. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I'm currently using a MigLayout, though it feels like it's more of a JLabel issue than something else.

To describe it at a high level, consider playing a game of cards in real life. When you hold cards in your hand normally, you only need to see part of the card, so much of the card is overlapped by another card, and so forth until the the final card is fully displayed since nothing is on top of it. I want to overlap in a way that only part of the cards underneath is shown, and then the top card is fully shown.

The current problem is that when I add a JLabel to a JPanel, it puts the newest label behind what is already there. I want it to be in front of what is already there. I can't seem to find any method that allows me to set which label is in front.

I want to do something like:

Put card1 in cell 0 0
Put card2 in cell 0 0 with a transposed y position
Any area where both cards overlapped has card2 on top

Simply adding it puts it behind, which suggests a first-come, first-serve priority on the display of a component. I'd rather have a last-come, first-serve priority. And like I've said, I have had no luck trying to find a method that allows any of this.

If any of this is unclear, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may require you to establish your own layout manager. You could carve it with some work with GridBagLayout, but I would suggest you needs are to localised for any of the existing layout managers to be able to support it well

Comment: Well, I'm not going back to GridBagLayout, I had bad experiences with it and I found it to be one of the most horrendous layout managers. I had so many problems with it that were fixed simply by redoing it in a different layout manager. I'd like to keep using the existing layout manager if possible.

Comment: `I'd like to keep using the existing layout manager if possible`. No it is not possible. The layout managers that come with the JDK lay out components in 2D without overlap. There is one layout in the JDK called OverlayLayout, but I've never been able to get it to work in any way that makes sense.

Comment: @camickr - I successfully got it working with the existing layout manager. All I had to do was set the z-component of the component. In my experience elsewhere with overlapping, z-components are fairly common and I would have been genuinely surprised if the solution actually required using a new layout manager.

Comment: @MichaelYousef, `I successfully got it working with the existing layout manager. ` - what layout manager? Do you mean MigLayout? That is not a standard layout manager. That is a third party layout manager. I have never used it. I did not realize it support this type of layout. So, yes, it does require using a new layout manager because it is not supported in the base JDK. Also, because you are manually setting the ZOrder, it is you who is actually doing the layout, not the layout manager. OverlapLayout does all the work for you.

Comment: @camickr - I stated originally that I am using a Mig Layout, so by saying I am using the existing layout manager means I am using what I was previously using, the Mig Layout. Secondly, I realize I'm manually setting the z-component and that I am directly in charge, but that's fine for me honestly. It wasn't difficult at all and since I'm setting components relative to each other and then just changing z-coordinates, it's not so much absolute positioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like JPanel inherits from Container, which has a method `setComponentZOrder()` which sounds like it does just what you need.

[setCompoentZOrder() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. It works a little awkwardly but I have it working now, so all is well.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Overlap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which explains a bit more about how ZOrder works and may even provide you with a layout manager to help in your card game.

Comment: +1 for being spot-on despite a shameless plug for your own Wordpress.

Comment: Didn't knew before, that such a fabulous Layout exists for such a work :-)